# Android: Swipey tabs without Action Bar

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-scrollable-tabs

I've created a `ViewPager`. and I want to add scrollable tabs (swipey tabs) to make it more flexible (like google play).
and all the tutorials that i found using `ActionBar`.
How can i do it without using `ActionBar`?

Comment: https://androidbeasts.wordpress.com/2015/08/11/tabs-with-swipe-views/#more-79

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[`PagerTabStrip`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/PagerTabStrip.html) and the tab flavor of [ViewPagerIndicator](http://viewpagerindicator.com/) should both give you swipey tabs.

Comment: The second link it seems to me it's using actionbar. not sure. but anyway I guess PagerTabStrip is what i need.thanks for your help :)

Comment: @IbrahimSwaiss: "The second link it seems to me it's using actionbar." -- ViewPagerIndicator is for use with `ViewPager` (that's why it is called ViewPagerIndicator) and has nothing directly to do with the action bar. The author of ViewPagerIndicator is the author of ActionBarSherlock, though.

Comment: it's more clear now, and thanks again, i just found what i'm looking for. wish me luck ;)

Comment: Can anybody please give the code(xml & java) for this..
I'm still not able to figure out, on how to use ViewPagerIndicator with PagerTabStrip.
Also, I think ViewPagerIndicator cannot be customized unless we are using an ActionBar.

Comment: `PagerTabStrip` how to make it look like `Tabs` as in `FragmentTabHost/TabHost`?

Answer (score 3):

This [link](http://thepseudocoder.wordpress.com/2011/10/13/android-tabs-viewpager-swipe-able-tabs-ftw/) will be helpful to you and you achieve that by following the example explained in the tutorial.

Or

You can search for `SupportV4Demos` in Samples and you can find the example FragmentTabs and Pager example to achieve that.

Comment: What i need is to make the tabs swipe with ViewPager, the example that you gave doesn't has swipey tabs. and thanks for your help, really appreciated :)

Comment: @IbrahimSwaiss why to swipe tabs, when you swipe the screens, it automatically tabs get swiped.